# Change Heroku start parameter

Tags: heroku

When I issue:
    heroku ps

i get:

```
=== web: `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`
```

Is there a way to change the spring profile to a different value?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the the spring profile using the cmd-line option `-Dspring.profiles.active=<profile name>` in your "Procfile" located at the root level of your Heroku app.

Hope this helps,
Matthias